# How to suppress Javadoc Warnings in Gradle Build?

Tags: java, java-21

Context:
I recently upgraded my Java project to Java 21 and accordingly updated Gradle to version 8.2. Post-update, I'm consistently encountering warnings in my console regarding missing Javadocs.

Problem:
I'm attempting to suppress these Javadoc warnings through my Gradle build script, but despite my efforts, the warnings persist. This is cluttering my build output and obscuring real issues.

First Attempt - Suppressing Specific Warnings:
I added the following to my Gradle build script to suppress warnings for missing Javadocs:

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:-missing', null)
}
```

Expected Outcome: No warnings for missing Javadoc comments.
Actual Outcome: The warnings remained.(`warning: no comment`)

Second Attempt - Disabling All Javadoc Warnings:
Next, I tried to disable all Javadoc-related warnings:

```
tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', null)
}
```

Expected Outcome: Complete suppression of Javadoc warnings and errors.
Actual Outcome: Warnings continued to appear as before.(`warning: no comment`)

Investigation:
Ran ./gradlew clean javadoc --info to check if the flags were being applied.
Discovered that options should be sourced from sample-project-gradle-docs/build/tmp/javadoc/javadoc.options.

Observation: This file did not include my specified options.
Testing Across Different JDKs:
Conducted tests with both OpenJDK 21.0.1 and Amazon Corretto 21.0.1.
Result: No change; the issue persists across both JDK versions.

Question:
How can I effectively pass these flags (-Xdoclint:-missing or -Xdoclint:none) to the Javadoc command in a Gradle build script for suppressing these warnings? Are there specific considerations for Gradle 8.2 or Java 21 that I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out the following works as expected but I have no idea why I have to pass the additional `-quiet` flag.

```
 tasks.withType(Javadoc).configureEach {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:-missing', '-quiet')
}
```